# Can I prevent roslaunch from changing the terminal screen title?

Tags: ros, roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This question was technically asked before back in 2014, but the answer was this was not possible at the time. I can't find any indication that this has changed, but has it been exposed for use? or can it be exposed - or is there a way I can get around it?

Would be super useful to be able to name the tabs based on what they are running rather than the current override is doing.

https://answers.ros.org/question/199845/how-do-i-prevent-roslaunch-from-changing-the-terminal-screen-title/?answer=200009#post-id-200009

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/399808/can-i-prevent-roslaunch-from-changing-the-terminal-screen-title?/) by [hwil292](https://answers.ros.org/users/29711/hwil292/) on ROS Answers with karma: 64 on 2022-04-27

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2022-04-28**:
Technically, the answer given by @tfoote in #q199845 is incorrect.

I've posted an additional answer there to point to your post here to avoid duplicating answers.

(and also technically, your post is now a duplicate, but it's a bit of a complex situation)

**Comment by [hwil292](https://answers.ros.org/users/29711/hwil292/) on 2022-04-28**:
Fair enough, and much appreciated for the answer!

Happy to have this removed or whatever is required to keep things tidy - in future, should I have followed up with a question within that original question?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2022-04-29**:
We can keep it open. As I wrote, I decided to answer your question instead of the one from 2014. With the links between the two we've sufficiently addressed discoverability I believe.

re: future questions: 'age' is certainly a good metric to determine when to post a new question. Especially when you find one that's already been answered: the old(er) one basically captures the "state of things" at the time it was asked (and answered).

> should I have followed up with a question within that original question?

your new post *is* a follow-up. Just as sites like Stack Overflow, ROS Answers works best with a 1-to-1 ratio of questions and answers, so posting follow-up questions in already answered posts isn't a good idea (visibility is really low, and you can only use comments, as answers are not for additional questions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, this was changed, in 2013 already actually. From the [CHANGELOG.rst](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/blob/52b0556dadf3ec0c0bc72df4fc202153a53b539e/tools/roslaunch/CHANGELOG.rst#1950-2013-10-04):

> add option to disable terminal title setting

the option referred to would be `--disable-title`:

```
$ roslaunch --help
...
  --disable-title       Disable setting of terminal title
...
```

This was added by [ros/ros_comm#288](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/pull/288).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2022-04-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1